# What is the opposite operation of print format string?

Tags: python, string, format, printf, string-formatting

In Python2.7, we have one way to print a formatted string:

```
print '%s has %d books and %f$' % ('Bob', 5, 2.21)
```

The `%s` `%d` `%f` is very like `printf` in C.

Is there an opposite operation to read a formatted string into variable,
just like `scanf` in C ?

For example, I want to assign a = 'Bob', b = 5, c = 2.21 with two string:

"Bob has 5 books and 2.21$" and "%s has %d books and %f$"

How can I implement this function ?

Comment: Also see the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-a-scanf-or-sscanf-equivalent).

Comment: str.format function is your friend